# UITableViewController inside UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitableview, iboutlet

I'm working on an Iphone project. In the storyboard I have `myViewController` containing few `UILabel`s and a `UITableView`.
The mentioned `UITableView` is referenced in the myViewController class by an IBOutlet :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *myTable;
```

Now I build a UITableViewController (myTableViewController) that I want to populate myTable.
Then I go back to myViewController and I allocate in here myTableViewController :

```
MyTableViewController *myTableViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
myTableViewController.tableView = myTable;
myTableViewController.tableView.delegate = myTableViewController;
myTableViewController.tableView.dataSource = myTableViewController;
```

It is not working (EXC_BAD_ACCESS error).
Usually I should populate myTable trough the UIViewController (making sure it conforms to nedeed protocols). But I'm really wondering If I can do what I did right above..

Comment: Did you connect your tableview to its filesowner, you also need to connect UITableview datasource and delegate .

Comment: What you mean for files owner? and where should i connect the UITableview datasource/delegate?

Comment: Why do you have a IBOutlet for myTable?

Comment: Are you sure you need a UITableViewController. You could add it as childViewController but maybe you would build your customViewController that have a UITableView inside it. So your customViewController must use the UITableViewControllerDelegate and UITableViewControllerDataSource protocols. You customViewController need a UITableView outlet as you written and then link the outlet and link the table delegate and datasource to your customViewController. Now everything should work fine.

Comment: @Gabriele I knew that thanks (It works like that,and thats how I ended up doing).But I was wondering if it was possible to implement a uitableviewcontroller from within a uiviewcontroller!

Answer (score 0):

Most cases you can solve this by creating a UIViewController and a reference to the table inside the ViewController using an IBOutlet. However, there are cases where you need a full blown UITableViewController, such as in core data, and you also would like the ability to add things like UIToolbars. I know, a lot of times you can hack a UINavigationController, but sometimes you don't want a hierarchy/stack. In such a case, admittedly fairly rare, one way to do this is to create a UITableViewController subclass. You can import and initialize it in your UIViewController class, create an outlet from the tableView sitting inside the UIViewController's nib/scene, and then assign the tableView property of the UITableViewController to the tableView outlet of the UIViewController.

```
self.instanceOfUITableVC.table = self.tableView
```

It's a bit complex, but it works. Now you can control the tableView using the UITableViewController subclass instance.